# scheduling realtime systems vs on-line systems vs batch systems

Tags: process, io, operating-system, cpu, scheduling

Im trying to understand how their scheduling criteria works. 
why IO bound and CPU bound mix are more important to batch processes?.
does Preemptive scheduling important to all?
thanks alot for the help.

Comment: You need to describe the system. Are you talking about a batch system or a system that can schedule batch and interactive processes at the same time?

Comment: a system that can schedule batch and interactive processes at the same time

Answer (score 0):

A mixed system typically allows the system manager to create batch queues into which those with appropriate privileges may submit jobs. Usual purpose of the batch queues is use the CPU when interactive processes are not using it.

Usually batch queues are assigned priorities that override the normal user priorities. The system manager usually assigns batch queues prior levels that are lower than the normal interactive priority. If you set the priority low enough, the batch queue does not interfere with interactive users.

It is also possible to schedule the batch queues so that they only run at specified times (e.g., between 2AM and 6AM).

The system manager does not concern himself with I/O bound or CPU bound.